# Using list comprehension to get the words with multiple (3) vowels in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Here is my question

```
fruits = ['mango', 'kiwi', 'strawberry', 'guava', 'pineapple', 'mandarin orange']

# Use a list comprehension to make a variable named fruits_with_more_than_two_vowels. Hint: You'll need a way to check if something is a vowel.
```

Can I do it in list comprehension alone?

Comment: Please provide your best attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: def fruits_check(x):
    count = 0
    for i in x:
        if i in 'aeiou':
            count += 1
    return x if count > 2 else None
        
    
fruits_with_vowels = list(map(fruits_check, fruits))
print(fruits_with_vowels)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Regular Expression pattern to filter out the consonants.

```py
import re

fruits = ["mango", "kiwi", "strawberry", "guava", "pineapple", "mandarin orange"]
results = [i for i in fruits if len(re.sub(r"[^aeiouAEIOU]", "", i)) > 2]
```

The above code yields the following output.

```py
>>> results
["guava", "pineapple", "mandarin orange"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def vowels_check(word):
    vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
    count = 0
    for vowel in vowels:
        count += word.count(vowel)
    if count > 2: return True
    return False

fruits = ['mango', 'kiwi', 'strawberry', 'guava', 'pineapple', 'mandarin orange']
fruits_with_more_than_two_vowels = [fruit for fruit in fruits if vowels_check(fruit)]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).